# sql server - converting date from mm/yyy to yyyymmgg

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, data-conversion

I have a column with date like this: mm/yyyy, for istance:

```
02/2022
12/2099
...
```

I need to convert them to yyymmgg format, where gg should be last day of that month, can  you help me?
I can get month and year by left(date, 2) and right(date, 5), how I can find the right day, especially  for february?

Comment: There's a [dedicated function for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql), even though it's not necessary for your case (because there's `DATEADD`, and the last day of February is the one before the first day of March).

Comment: That's just a string, not a date. Dates have no format, they are binary values. In the very few cases you need to store a string, like this one, use `YYYYMM` or `YYYY-MM` to allow proper sorting and indexing

Comment: A better idea would be to store dates as dates and use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) to look up years, months, quarters, FirstOfMonth or EndOfMonth values etc. This makes querying and grouping  a *lot* easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to a date using some string manipulation and `convert()`.  Then just use `eomonth()`:

```
select eomonth(convert(date, '01/' + mmyyyy, 103))
```

I would recommend that you leave the value as a date.  You can, of course, convert back to a string if that is what you really want.